# Confusion in Gravitation Foundation and Frontiers?

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics

Taken from Gravitation: Foundations and Frontiers by T. Padmanabhan Pg $197$

> Consider a bunch of particles moving along geodesics in a spacetime. Let $x_i = x_i
> (\tau,v)$ denote the
> family of geodesics, where $\tau$ represents an affine parameter along the geodesics and
> $v$ labels a particular geodesic. The vector
> $$n_i = (\partial x_i
> / \partial v) \delta v \equiv v_i$$
> $\delta v$ denotes the
> deviation between two neighboring geodesics parametrized by the values $v$ and
> $v +dv$. From the definition of the covariant derivative and the relation $(\partial u_i
> / \partial v) =
> \partial v_i / \partial τ$ (where $u_i$ is the tangent vector to the geodesic), it follows that:
>
> $$ v^k \nabla_k u^i = u^k \nabla_k v^i$$

I'm still confused about this passage. Can someone provide an explicit example of family of curves dependent of $v$? And secondly, how does one go from $$(\partial u_i
/ \partial v) = \partial v_i / \partial τ$$
to
$$ v^k \nabla_k u^i = u^k \nabla_k v^i$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the surface of the Earth.  It is a 2-sphere, i.e. a 2-dimensional manifold, named $M$.  The collection of all longitude lines is a bunch of geodesics, each line is labeled by its longitude ($v$).  Each point on a specific line is labeled by its latitude ($\tau$).  So every point on the surface of the Earth is labeled by a pair of number $(v, \tau)$, which serves as a good coordinate system of the surface.  The coordinate basis of the tangent bundle $TM$ is then $\{\xi \equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial v}, u \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}\}$, and we have for a coordinate basis
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
[u,\xi] = 0 \quad\text{or}\quad \mathcal{L}_{u} \xi=0
\end{equation}
or explicitly, $\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$.

In an arbitrary coordinate system $(x^{i})$ of $M$, we have
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\xi = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial v} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \equiv \xi^i \partial_i, \quad\quad u = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial\tau} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \equiv u^i \partial_i.
\end{equation}
Substituting (2) into (1), we obtain
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
u^i \partial_i \xi^j - \xi^i \partial_i u^j = 0.
\end{equation}
From the definition of covariant derivative, we have
\begin{equation}
u^i \nabla_i \xi^j = u^i \partial_i \xi^j + \Gamma^j_{ik} u^i \xi^k \quad\text{and}\quad \xi^i \nabla_i u^j = \xi^i \partial_i u^j + \Gamma^j_{ik} \xi^i u^k
\end{equation}
For Riemann connection, we have
$\Gamma^j_{ik} = \Gamma^j_{ki}$, then $\Gamma^j_{ik} u^i \xi^k = \Gamma^j_{ik} \xi^i u^k$.  We finally obtain
\begin{equation}
u^i \nabla_i \xi^j - \xi^i \nabla_i u^j = u^i \partial_i \xi^j - \xi^i \partial_i u^j = 0.
\end{equation}